# Does alerting a dog cause you to lose the no alerts 3,000 points bonus?

Tags: mark-of-the-ninja

At the start of the Voice of the Hisomu section, the game introduces dogs with a section that's smaller than the dog's sniffing radius; the dog patrols the section so I'm really at a loss for how to get through cleanly.

That doesn't mean I can't get through, but I'll alert the dog. Doing this however does not cause the 800 points "Detected!" penalty. Does it perhaps screw you out of the end-of-level no alerts bonus as well?

Comment: I can't quite remember exactly, but I think alerting dogs doesn't matter, but if they bark and end up alerting a human then you'll lose the bonus.  I think if you 'surprise' a dog and then take it out you should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to avoid the first dog without alerting it or even having the yellow "interest" circle appear.

You need to be on the right hand wall and as the dog travels to the far left, you can swing down and under and continue to the right along the roof without alerting the dog.

In terms of the "no alarms raised" bonus, you should see the red text with the -800 score appear if an alarm is raised at all. The yellow circle of "interest" doesn't break the no-alert bonus.

Comment: I don't believe a state of "interest" on a guard's part counts for the "no alarms raised" bonus, either, for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

No, alerting the dogs does not cause you to lose the "no alerts" 3,000 points bonus.